# Django: You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP. code 400, message Bad request version

Tags: django, http, https

I am trying to access my Django website using

> python manage.py runserver

, which returns me `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. However, when I try to access this link using Google chrome, I get this error on chrome

> This site can’t provide a secure connection 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid

On Anaconda prompt, I get this error:

```
Code 400, message Bad request version ('ª')
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

I notice that Google Chrome always changes my website to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I am uncertain if this is the issue because. I have been working on the Django project and have been accessing the website on chrome using the same method and there was no issues with it at all. Could it be because of the settings.py configurations that caused the error?

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku     # to host heroku
import dj_database_url   # to host heroku
from decouple import config  # to host heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-d44=xloa_ngo&moz%cujtvuqpr7ub)hfbqss6$xnubj031q3!9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.16.130', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '0.0.0.0']

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False

# !!! Added for CSRF protection

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
#CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ 
    "http://0.0.0.0:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://192.168.16.130:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://0.0.0.0:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://192.168.16.130:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
'DELETE',
'GET',
'OPTIONS',
'PATCH',
'POST',
'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',                      # !!! Added for CSRF 
    'hospital'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',                # !!! Added for CSRF
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',               # !!! Added for CSRF 
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hospital.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hospital.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',   #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'aws_db',
        'HOST': 'database-2.cxjd4rzryhvg.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5430',
        'USER': 'jolinsiow_db',
        'PASSWORD': 'jolinsiow'
    }
}

'''
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_pharmUI_v3',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'jolinsiow'
    }
}
'''

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
# Capture exceptions
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'hospital.exception.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it was intended, but you included something that looks like correct credentials to your AWS database

Comment: browser sometimes cache the HTTPS redirect, it's better for you to clear the browser cache or open the browser in incognito to test it(after restarting the Django server ofcourse)